# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist with any hibernate.ddl-auto

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to run Hibernate using annotations. But after calling `buildSessionFactory()` tables are not generated. I guess t Here is my code:

```
public class HibernateApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
        session.save(entity);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            Properties properties = PropertiesReader.get();
            configuration.setProperties(properties);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(app.model.TestEntity.class);
            configuration.buildMappings();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.181:1521:center
hibernate.connection.username=username
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true
```

Edit: 
It may be important to mention that I tried to build this project using hibernate, but **not** Spring. I guess had that problem because most of the tutorials imply using Hibernate with Spring and there is some overlap in dependencies.

Comment: Do you see any error/exception?

Comment: Check the config files and also check the annotations are correctly placed

Comment: @Codified Before insertion I see only warning about “JNDI” not found. On insert I see error that table not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when instead of `hibernate-core` dependency I used `hibernate-entitymanager`. Then I used just Configuration instead of AnnotationConfiguration. With the first dependency, I can't find `addAnnotatedClass` method.

Then Hibernate started to create tables after calling

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                    .addAnnotatedClass(app.model.TestEntity.class)
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```